# SSRS bar char x-axis formatting

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I've got a chart that overlays the past 2 years (taken from the current date) worth of data onto a 1 year range, so the monthly values can be compared between years. The x-axis values are week numbers.

Currently, I've got the x-axis like this:

```
--------------------   etc
1   2   3   4   5
```

What I want is to start the x-axis with the week for the earliest date in my data set, so my x-axis looks like this:

```
--------------------------...-------
49  50  51  52  1   2   3 ... 47  48
```

How do I get the chart control to get my x-axis to appear like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have another column that contains the year, sort by this first, then the week number, then only display the week number in the axis.

So assuming your data is something like:

[image]

You would apply two sorts to the category group, `Year` then `Week`, but only display `Week` in the axis label.

[image]

[image]

I have left all the **Category Axis Properties** as default:

[image]

This gives the expected result:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. The minimum is still calculated as the minimum week in the dataset and that is what appears at the start of the x-axis. I've tried setting the min value of the x-axis to the weeknumber of the earliest date, but that doesn't solve the wrapping of the weeks from 52 to 1 in the middle of the axis.

Comment: You shouldn't need to apply any min or max logic. I've expanded the answer with a working example.

Comment: Ah, got it working now - I'd not set my axis to 'category'... doh.